# Construct a natural bijection map

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone show me how to create a "Natural Bijection Map":

$$f:{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}\,/\,{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$$
Where R is the equivelance relation:

$$(a.b)R(c,d)\rightarrow a+d=b+c$$

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what? I am using LaTeX

Comment: Did you try $f(a, b) = a-b$?

Comment: $f([(a,b)])=b-a$ should work here. Prove that $f$ is well defined, injective and finally surjective (this part is obvious)

Comment: I've never created a bijection map before using an equivelance relation. Im brand new to this, so im not really sure even how to get started. How does f(a,b)=a-b help me?

Comment: Isn't there nothing to show since that is how one constructs $\mathbb{Z}$? That is, we *define* the set $\mathbb{Z}$ to be $\frac{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}{R}$...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider $g:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $g(a,b)=a-b$. What is the kernel of $g$?

(The [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(set_theory)) is the equivalence relation  $x \sim y$ iff $g(x)=g(y)$.)